# E4 doesn´t invoke my @PostConstruct-Method

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I´m having trouble with the migration of my E3-RCP-Application to a E4.
There I got 3 parts. 2 with Sample Content of Lars Vogel (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#plugin_creatinge4 "Using the SWT power widget") to test and compare it with my part.

Long Story short(er): The Method that should create the View´s content, marked with @PostConstruct, won´t be invoked, but the @PostConstruct of the SampleContent would. What reasons could that have?
The Constructor of MyView is invoked.

The Structure of my View is as the following:

```
Many Imports

public class MyView1 implements IRefreshableView, ISomeListener {

a lot of fields, some are injected...

public MyView1()  {
        reference to the Activator-Class to get some item.
    }

@PostConstruct
public void createControls(Composite parent) {
        createViewToolbar();``

and much more Part Creation stuff that won´t be invoked...

}

much more methods
@Focus
    public void setFocus() {
        if (treeViewer.getTree().isVisible()) {
            treeViewer.getTree().setFocus();
        } else {
            mainForm.setFocus();
        }
    }

}

new class definition in the same file. 

END
```

Sorry for not posting the whole Code, it´s like 1000 rows long :/

I´m using Mars 4.5.1 on Win7

Comment: How is this class being created? Is it listed as a part in the Application.e4xmi?

Comment: Exactly. The class-URI is pointing to the MyView1-class. As well as the ID is the same

Comment: Possibly the injector is having trouble with some of the fields you haven't shown. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: So u mean only the @Inject Fields, right ?

Comment: Yes. `@Inject` fields are injected before the `@PostConstruct` method is run. If something can't be resolved the injector may stop.

Comment: Wow, this fixed it, you´re awesome! I´m new to Stack overflow, may I give u Reputation without a real Post? The Problem was a MToolBar injection, from wich i thought I could get out of the Context.

Comment: Don't worry about rep, helping is the main thing.

Comment: I have added a answer to help anyone else having similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cause of the `@PostConstruct` failing to run is the Direct Injection code not being able to find objects which are injected in fields (or an injected constructor). If this happens the injector just logs an error and stops.

The error is logged in the '.log' file in the workspace '.metadata' directory.